# How to create a separate theme for a custom page?

Tags: 7, theming

How to create a custom theme for a page? I want to create a template for my `example/123` page.

Comment: Context Layouts...

Answer (score 1):

To create a *custom template* for `node/123`, copy your theme's default `page.tpl.php` to a file named `page--node--123.tpl.php` (D7) in your theme's or subtheme's `templates/` directory, and then edit it to do any customization.

To do custom *theming*, add custom classes where you need them in the custom template, and then add the CSS to style those classes.

Btw.: I usually do this by creating a sub-theme, to avoid any customization from being overwritten when the super-theme is upgraded.

PS: If your page really has the path `example/123`, the name of the template overide file should be `page--example--123.tpl.php`

Remember to clear the cache after doing this.    Until you do, your override will not be visible.

Comment: Need To describe any thing in template.php ?

Comment: There is usually no need to change `template.php` unless you're changing more than just appearance.  Drupal will pick up the override based upon its name alone.

Comment: But This is not page type. then any changes need?

Comment: If it is not a page type, then overriding the page template won't work.  Please edit your question and explain in detail what you mean by "example/123 page".

Comment: its my call back menu item. from which i loading a drupal form . and i want to themes this thanks